# Pan gesture in UITableView blocks touchesEnded:withEvent:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITableView` and added a custom `UIGestureRecognizer`. Now `touchesBegan:withEvent:` of my `UIGestureRecognizer` always gets called but if the same gesture gets interpreted as a pan gesture by the table view, too, than `touchesEnded:withEvent:` never gets called. This makes my gesture recognizer useless because you have to do a perfect, straight and horizontal swipe and that almost never happens.

I really would appreciate your help.

Comment: all touches event has nothing to do with UIGestureRecognizer. Gesture work with its gesture recogniser. What do you want to do with touchesBegan:withEvent: ?

Comment: I use these in my custom gesture recognizer. If I remove all standard UIGestureRecognizers from the UITableView it works great..